# Parameterize tests using excel in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I'm new to Python and have written few tests in Pytest. I want to now parameterize my tests using excel or csv sheet to pass the data to test methods.

I've not been able to find any help. Could you please help me with it or refer to any link.

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Try writing a function to retrieve a list of your "data" from your excel or CSV. Then you could utilize the parametrize function like so:

```
def get_data():
    # Retrieve values from CSV
    return ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value", get_data())
def test_sample(self, value):
    print(value)
```

This example would generate 3 tests passing each element returned from `get_data()` as value.

Note: Checkout the documentation on CSV https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html for help with how to open a CSV file and convert the values to a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea should be use [parametrized test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html).

For instance you can add an input parameter with the input filename

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I need to install any package like pandas or openpyxl to read the excel file and then pass the data row by row? or I just need to pass the excel filename? There isn't any example on the page using file as input data.

Comment: of course reading excel files needs some extra packages. my answer was more about how to read the test input from a file